# Replacing View Controllers programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I'm using a library ([ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)) to have a sliding view. I believe my problem would apply to any other library.

I have the following code in my Initial View Controller:

```
#import "InitialViewController.h"

@implementation InitialViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                     bundle:nil];
    self = [super initWithCenterViewController:[storyboard
                                                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"middleViewController"]
                            leftViewController:[storyboard
                                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];

    return self;
}

@end
```

There are times when I need to present a ViewController modally and then, depending on the user's input, swap the current View Controllers;
For example, I would need to swap *middleViewController* for *mainViewController* and *leftViewController* for *menuViewController*.
I can't come up with a way for doing this.  I thought of using delegates on the Initial View Controller, but I believe that delegate code is lost when I call *self = [super initWith...]* on the code above.

Is there a way to swap these controllers? Should I be replacing the rootViewController? If so, how?

Comment: From the docs, in ViewDeck you can just set the property to switch view controllers?

Comment: @verbumdei yes, I can do that from within InitialViewController, but I don't think I can do it from the other controllers (e.g. middleViewController or leftViewController)... it could probably be done if I pass around a reference to InitialViewController, but it doesn't like a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) instead of ViewDeck.  Their implementation is, I believe, cleaner and easier to customize.